# A question on BSD conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory

If $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $K$ is an imaginary quadratic field. If $rank E(K)\leq 1$ and both $E$ and the quadratic twist of $E$ by $K$ satisfy the full BSD conjecture, does the base change of $E$ to $K$ satisfy the full BSD conjecture?

Answer (score 10):

Yes.

This follows from the fact that BSD is invariant under Weil restriction and isogeny (the Weil restriction of $E/K$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ is isogenous to the product of $E$ with its quadratic twist).

Note that you don't need to assume here that $K$ is imaginary nor anything about the rank of $E/K$.

Comment: Thanks. In a lot of cases, we know that the $p$-part of full BSD of $E$ and the quadratic twist of $E$ holds, by Skinner et. all. So what is the answer if we focus the question on the $p$-part of full BSD conjecture?

Comment: Im guessing the answer is probably yes here, though I don't know references. I would recommend examining the proofs of invariance of BSD under Weil restriction and isogeny, and see if they can be adapted to this setting.

Comment: You are right. I chase the proofs of Milne in http://www.jmilne.org/math/articles/1972a.pdf and "Arithmetic duality theorem". The two invariances are proved by comparing each ingredient one by one. So the equivalence on $p$-part should holds.