# Elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ vs over $K$

Tags: nt.number-theory

I saw the paper claiming the proof of the BSD conjecture for the CM case. 
Apart from the truth and falsehood of this paper, I noticed that the author 
says that the congruent number problem can be solved if the BSD conjecture 
for CM elliptic curves over an imaginary quadratic field $K$. I think that 
the congruent number problem is a problem over $\mathbb{Q}$. Is it possible 
to deduce it as a corollary of **true BSD** over an imaginary quadratic field $K$?
More precisely, my question is 
$$L(E_K,s)=r(E(K))\Longrightarrow L(E_{\mathbb{Q}},s)=r(E(\mathbb{Q}))?$$

http://kazuma-morita.jimdo.com/app/download/12319896690/Sh.BSD.pdf?t=1452154642

(I know that he withdraw a paper claiming the full BSD from the arxiv at 2013.)

Comment: Yes this follows from the fact that BSD is invariant under Weil restriction and isogeny. See my answer to this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/179764/a-question-on-bsd-conjecture/179770#179770. (This shows that BSD for E and its quadratic twist is equivalent to BSD for E_K)